# Show Loader for multiple buttons

Tags: html, jquery

I want to show loader on icon/button click. In foreach loop, there is a list with delete icon. While click delete icon i want to show loader near that particular icon. I am using like below.

Html code:

```
<span id="deletefile">
     <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
     <div class='loader' style='display:none'></div>
 </span>
```

Jquery code:

```
$('span#deletefile').click(function() {
  $('#deletefile').find('.loader').show(); 
}
```

Since it is a loop, the loader visible near each delete icons.
How to show loader at particular click icon. Pls give me idea

Edited as per Satya S answer. It triggers always first icon. Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+delete+spinner+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Add IDs to each element and show and hide based on the ID.

Comment: $('.btn-delete').closest('li').find('.loader').show() ............

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating that html in a loop you will have multiple elements with the same id which is invalid.
Instead, use a class.

```
<span class="deletefile">
     <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
     <div class='loader' style='display:none'></div>
</span>
```

```
$('span.deletefile').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.loader').show(); 
}
```

Comment: Yes... Working.. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Add `id` attribute to your button. Then you should be able to do -

```
$('#delete-button-id').find('.loader').show()
```

This is will find the child loader to each delete button and show that.
Make sure the loader is a child of the delete button with the id.

Comment: hi, I did as you told. It always trigger first icon. While click next row icon, it displayed at first row. Where i am doing wrong?